# Pb with Jquery Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to change options of a list dynamicaly with Ajax.
Here's my code (simplified for more convenience) :

```
//Ajax request here ....

$('#my_select').empty();
$('#my_select').append(new_options_in_html);
```

So far so good, the previous options are deleted and the new ones are inserted 
in the #my_select list (checked with Firebug).
The problem is that the new options won't display in the list.

Seemingly the Chosen plugin generates this code for the display:

```
<div id="my_select_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 27px;" title="">
    <a class="chzn-single chzn-default" tabindex="-1">
        <span>Select an option</span>
        <div>
            <b></b>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="chzn-drop">
        <div class="chzn-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
        </div>
        <ul class="chzn-results"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "fake" options should be displayed in ul chzn-results, but 
in my case nothing happens.

```
$('#my_select').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Doesn't work.

```
$('#my_select').toggle('chosen:updated');
```

The list appears as rough html and disappears whenever options change.

So can someone helps me Please ?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: After appending the new options, you should call $('#my_select').chosen() again

Comment: where is `my_select` id in your html code?

Comment: my_select id is in the select list just above the html code I've just posted:

<select id="my_select" class="chzn-done" aria-required="true" required="" name="my_select" style="display: none;">
<option selected="selected" value="">- Selectionner</option>
<option value="260">Option 1</option>
<option value="040">Option 2</option>
 ...
</select>

Comment: $('#my_select').chosen() doesn't work.
How should I use it ?